# How to execute a php script from another php script by using the shell?

Tags: php, shell, shell-exec

I have a php file called `sample.php` with the following content:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>
```

And what I want to do, is to run this php script using a second php script.

I think `shell_exec` could help me, but I don't know its syntax.

By the way, I want to execute this files with `cpanel`. So I have to execute the shell.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You'd rather execute it in another process, invoking the shell and all that, than simply `include` it?

Comment: You can say `include "other_script.php";` to run the script within the same PHP instance, rather than spawning another interpreter.  There are valid reasons to want a distinct process...but unless you have to, `include` is usually better.

Comment: No i have to run through it shell because i want to make an php online editor

Comment: I had tried this $script_output = shell_exec("php $myfile 2> output"); but this code return nothing.

Comment: If you have to ask this question here, then you are not ready to write an online php editor and deal with all the security issues this will raise.

Comment: [exec function](http://php.net/function.exec)? well, to just run php code you could also use [eval](http://www.php.net/eval)

Comment: no i have not tried that

Comment: Are you trying to have one php file execute another php file and anything it writes have it write into a buffer?

Comment: Yes ut writes in buffer and i am taking the output from buffer by this code ob_get_contents();

Comment: I added an answer below but I'm still not sure if that's what you need.

Comment: I think that instead of asking how to achieve this (for what you have a lot of valid answers), you should go one step back and explain the scenario, and what functionality you need, since i bet that this is not a correct approach for whatever you are trying to do, and probably you will have many problems in the future

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you need to write a php file's output into a variable use the ob_start and ob_get_contents functions. See below:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    include('myfile.php');
    $myStr = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    echo '>>>>' . $myStr . '<<<<';
?>
```

So if your 'myfile.php' contains this:

```
<?php
    echo 'test';
?>
```

Then your output will be:

```
>>>>test<<<<
```

Comment: Hi i had tried your suggestion. It worked. But i am taking data from editor and storing that data into file using this code $d=rand();
  $myfile=$d.".php";
  //file_put_contents($myfile,"code: ",FILE_APPEND);
  file_put_contents($myfile,"<?php "."\n",FILE_APPEND);
  file_put_contents($myfile,$code."\n",FILE_APPEND);
  file_put_contents($myfile,"?>"."\n",FILE_APPEND); so you can understand from my code that each time the file name should be different. i had tried this include($myfile); but it returns an error that no such file is found. So how can i do this

Comment: I'm not sure I see the problem. Just include the correct file. If it's named differently every time shouldn't you have a handle to the name of it somewhere?

Answer (score 4):

You can use cURL for remote requests.  The below is from php.net:

```
<?php
// create a new cURL resource
$ch = curl_init();

// set URL and other appropriate options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

// grab URL and pass it to the browser
curl_exec($ch);

// close cURL resource, and free up system resources
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Here's a good tutorial: http://www.sitepoint.com/using-curl-for-remote-requests/

Consider watching this YouTube video here as well:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M2HLGZJi0Hk

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

**Main PHP file**

```
<?php
// change path/to/php according to how your system is setup
// examples: /usr/bin/php or /opt/lampp/bin/php
echo shell_exec("/path/to/php /path/to/php_script/script.php");
echo "<br/>Awesome!!!"
?>
```

**Secondary PHP file**

```
<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>
```

**Output when running Main PHP file**

```
Hello World!
Awesome!!!
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: It is also return empty data. How can i find what is the error

Comment: If "Hello World!" above is not displayed, the error be displayed instead because of the "echo" before "shell_exec".

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
// change path/to/php according to how your system is setup
// examples: /usr/bin/php or /opt/lampp/bin/php
$output = shell_exec("/path/to/php /path/to/php_script/script.php");
print_r($output);
?>
```

This May Help you.

Answer (score 1):

It's important to stress that including/executing user-generated code is dangerous. Using a system call (`exec`, `shell_exec`, `system`) instead of `include` helps separate the execution context, but it's not much safer. Consider proper sanitation or sand-boxing.

With that in mind, here is a working example including generating the (temporary) file, executing it, and cleanup:

```
<?php
   // test content  
   $code = <<<PHP
   echo "test";
PHP;

   // create temporary file
   $d=rand();
   $myfile="$d.php";
   file_put_contents($myfile,"<?php\n$code\n?>");

   // start capture output
   ob_start();

   // include generate file
   // NOTE: user-provided code is unsafe, they could e.g. replace this file.
   include($myfile);

   // get capture output
   $result = ob_get_clean();

   // remove temporary file
   unlink($myfile);

   // output result
   echo "================\n" . $result . "\n================\n" ;
```

Output:

```
================
test
================
```

Answer (score 0):

```
terminal view:
abgth@ubuntu:/var/www$ cat > test.php

  <?php
      echo shell_exec("php5 /var/www/check.php");     
  ?>

abgth@ubuntu:/var/www$ cat > check.php
  <?php
      echo 'hi';
  ?>
abgth@ubuntu:/var/www$ php5 test.php
hi
```

> I hope you are looking for this

Answer (score -3):

Go to terminal and type

php filename.php

filename.php should be the name of file you want to execute!

Comment: He is trying to have this execute at runtime.